# A simple simulation example in R from a textbook

Tags: r, statistics

I found this piece of code from a the textbook "Statistics and Data analysis for financial engineering," but I am confused about certain line in this code:

This code tried to answer the question of What is the probability that the value of the stock will be below $950,000 at the close of at least one of the next 45 trading days? They provide the mean and SD too.

Code:

```
niter = 1e5 # number of iterations
below = rep(0,niter) # set up storage
set.seed(2009)
for (i in 1:niter)
{
    r = rnorm(45,mean=.05/253,
    sd=.23/sqrt(253)) # generate random numbers
    logPrice = log(1e6) + cumsum(r)
    minlogP = min(logPrice) # minimum price over next 45 days
    below[i] = as.numeric(minlogP < log(950000))
}

mean(below)
```

A few questions:

1. I dont understand about `logPrice = log(1e6) + cumsum(r)`, why we use `log(1e6)` and why we have `cumsum(r)`?
2. What is the purpose of this: `below[i] = as.numeric(minlogP < log(950000))`
3. why do we use `log(950000)`? why do we need to `log`?

Comment: To Nishanth:I understand that stock price is log-normal in many quant analysis. But somehow I was looking at the question again, and is it also because we are interested in the probability, so we use log? But if so, I still don't understand the connection between using log to model the probability.

Comment: you can work out the same equations without taking log. Then return `r` should be multiplied with `price` (instead of adding) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm guessing that current price is $100,000 and hence `log(1e6)`. The return has to be accumulated over period of 45 days and therefore `cumsum(r)`
2. Well you are checking if price falls below $950,000
3. In quant the stock return is normally distributed and stock price (always +ve) is log-normal.